# When x became 40, y should be 0 right? How did the output became 1 in the 4th iteration, when y = 0?

Tags: c, factorial

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num = 40585;
    int output = 0;

    for (int x = num; x > 0; x /=10)
    {
        int temp = 1;
        int y = x % 10;

        for (int i = y; i > 1; i--)
            temp *= i;

        output += temp;
    }

    if (output == num)
        printf("True");
    else
        printf("False");
}
```

I thought when i became 0, the statement in the inner for loop would not run so output would be 0. When added all, I thought the result was 40584.

Comment: Sounds like a good job for a debugger.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? What problem is it supposed to solve? What is your assignment or exercise?

Comment: When `y == 0` this `output += temp;` is effectively `output++;`

Comment: Instead of a debugger, some simple printf() functions can also help for a first stab at debugging the problem.

Comment: the code is about sum of factorial

Comment: « When x became 40, y should be 0 right? » Right. « Why should the inner for loop still run when i > 1 is false? » It should not; what makes you think it does? Please add your answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `x` is 40, `y` is set to 0, and no iterations of the loop on `i` are executed.

This leaves `temp` unchanged. `temp` was initialized to 1, so it remains 1, and `output += temp` adds 1 to `output`.

This matches the mathematical definition of the factorial of 0, as 0! = 1.